# Как создать потоки

Tags: c#

Как мне прописать три потока, чтобы они шли параллельно то есть 
1)a-9
2)aa-99
3)aaa-999
уже столько времени убил из-за этого, поэтому тут спрашиваю...

Comment: Что есть "a-9", "aa-99" и "aaa-999"?

Comment: Разместите код, на который Вы "уже столько времени убили".

Comment: a-9 это abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
aa-99 тоже самое только два рядом, аналог и дальше(три рядом)

Comment: @MaxZS да я прощу помощи т.к. не нашел в нете ответа

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa - А-а-а, теперь понятно :(. Только не мне.

Comment: А что не понятно ?

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa Что куда шло параллельно, и что это за алфавитно-цифровые последовательности?

Comment: потоки, то есть параллельно первый со вторым и третьем

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa да вообще ничего не понятно. Вы очень плохо объясняете. Что за азбуку Морзе вы привели, кто там куда параллельно идёт,что именно вы сделали сами?

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa - "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" - это поток?

Comment: Если Вам было выдано задание, то не придумывайте сами, а напишите его как есть. Но решать его за Вас никто не станет. Для того, чтобы Вам помогли с ним справиться, сначала покажите, что Вы уже сделали самостоятельно. Просто "погуглил и ничего не нашел" - это не причина для помощи в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: Я пробовал что-то на подобии этого https://habrahabr.ru/post/126495/, но не знаю как дальше быть, а эти буквы, 
a-9(a,b,c,d,e,f,...,A,B,C,D,E,...,,,0,1,2,3,...,9)
aa-99 (тоже самое (aa,ab,ac,..................99)
aaa-999(тоже самое (aaa,aab,aac,.......999)
как-то так

Comment: Если у Вас проблема в синхронном выводе букв из потоков, то при внимательном изучении своей же ссылки, Вы должны были бы как минимум понять, что работать синхронно потоки не будут. Каждый из потоков будет работать только тогда, когда ему будет выделен квант времени и столько времени, сколько будет ему позволено. Если у Вас проблема в том, чтобы вообще выводить по порядку буквы, то так и напишите. Кстати, насколько я понял, при таком выводе первый поток закончится намного раньше второго и третьего, а второй - намного раньше третьего.

Comment: @MaxZS именно так мне и надо, ток я не знаю как записать

Comment: Пожалуйста перенесите суть вопроса из комментариев в вопрос. В текущем виде он не несет никакой пользы сообществу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенной Вам [ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126495/) замените первый цикл на

```
for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Поток 1 выводит " + str[j].ToString());
    Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

Второй цикл замените на

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Поток 2 выводит " + str[i].ToString() + str[j].ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Вначале программы в классе перед функцией Main добавьте

```
static string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

Для третьего потока все делается аналогично второму.

Comment: Здесь не курсы по изучению языка программирования. Изучите для начала Си (без указателей - они не нужны для С#). Синтаксис языка и его конструкции не такие сложные.

Comment: не поможете, тогда все равно

Comment: Надеюсь, последний комментарий наглядно продемонстрировал вам, к чему ведут ответы на такие вопросы. Автор садится на шею и не слезет, пока вы за него не сделаете все лабы, курсовые и диплом. А спасибо не будет, нам же и так тут деньги платят за ответы. ))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36488/discussion-on-answer-by-max-zs---).